# How to stop popup not to hide in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a popup in which I made a toggle with the help of pure CSS. Now if I run The popup and move my mouse at the uppermost or the lowermost part of the window the popup start disappeared if my cursor is place at the body part its start appears. I am using 0% JAVASCRIPT inside my popup code.
here is the issue:https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPe7E.jpg
focus on the mouse cursor! Also, I am looking a way to open a popup at the page load without js.

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog:target,.modalDialog:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog>#__spookyPopup {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}

.profile_container {
  height: 160px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #;
  display: inline-block;
}

.profile_div {
  height: 120px;
  width: 130px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.head_div {
  min-height: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}



.priv_cont {
  height: 90px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #;
  display: inline-block;
}

.priv_head {
  height: 60px;
  width: 330px;
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-top:15px;
  background: #;

  
}




.clicker {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: ;
  color: #FFF;
}

.clicker:hover{border-bottom: 2px solid red ;
}


#click_styling
{
margin-top:20px;
height: 50px;
 width: 197px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;color:#000;
 line-height:50px;
 text-decoration:none;
 cursor:default;"

}
.clicker.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.hiddendiv {
  height: 0px;
  background-color: ;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}


.social {
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #;
  display: inline-block;
}

.social_link {
  height: 60px;
  width: 330px;
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-top:15px;
  background: #;
 
  
}
.manual_link
{
  height: 35px;
  width: 330px;
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-top:30px;
  background: #e3e3e3;
   border-bottom:2px solid red;
  }
  

.hiddendiv.nr2 {
  background-color: ;
}

#showdiv1:target~div a[href="#showdiv1"],
#showdiv2:target~div a[href="#showdiv2"] {
  display: none;
}

#showdiv1:target~div a[href="#hidediv1"],
#showdiv2:target~div a[href="#hidediv2"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

#showdiv1:target~div .hiddendiv.nr1,
#showdiv2:target~div .hiddendiv.nr2 {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#__spooky_auth_popup">Open Modal</a>

<div id="__spooky_auth_popup" class="modalDialog">
  <div id="__spookyPopup">

    <div class="profile_container">
      <div class="profile_div"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="head_div">
      <p style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;
font-size:25px;color:#8d8686;">
      <I>Hey, please login to access your private content.</I>
      </p>
    </div>


    <div id="showdiv1"></div>
      <div id="showdiv2"></div>

        <div>
          <a href="#showdiv1" class="clicker "  id="click_styling" tabindex="1">SOCIAL</a>
          <a href="#hidediv1" class="clicker hidden "  id="click_styling" tabindex="1">SOCIAL</a>

          <a href="#showdiv2" class="clicker "  id="click_styling" tabindex="2">MANUAL</a>
          <a href="#hidediv2" class="clicker hidden "  id="click_styling" tabindex="2">MANUAL</a>

          <div class="hiddendiv nr1">
            <div class="social">
              <div class="social_link"> 
                <div data-html="allow" style="margin-left:80px;margin-top:10px;">
                  <iframe  id="iFrame1"  style="border: 0px;  display: block" height="400" class="spoooky-auth" src="https://api.spooo.ky/auth/facebook" border="0"></iframe>
                </div>
                <!-- End of facebook button -->
              </div>

              <div class="social_link">
                <!-- Optional: Linkedin button starts here -->
                <div data-html="allow" style="margin-left:95px;margin-top:10px;">
                <iframe style="border: 0px;  display: inline-block" class="spoooky-auth" src="https://api.spooo.ky/auth/linkedin" border="0"></iframe>
                <!-- End of linkedin button -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="hiddendiv nr2">
          <div class="social">
            <div class="manual_link" > 
              <p style="text-align:left;font-size:25px;color:#979191;line-height:50px;">
              <I>WaterMark Text</I></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="priv_cont">
        <div class="priv_head">
          <p style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;font-size:18px;color:#000;">
            <I>By continuing to the content you agree with the <a href="#"  style="color:#000;">cookie</a> 
  and <a href="#" style="color:#000;">privacy</a> policies.</I>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Any Idea? what was the issue? and how can I prevent it? Any input is appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Since the modal appears when hovering anywhere on `.modalDialog`, the user never gets a chance to click on the "Open Modal" link. You'll only get the modal to stay up by using `:target`. Using `:hover` causes the modal to hide when the user's cursor leaves the page.

Answer (score 0):

The 'issue' seen in your code snippet is caused by using `:hover` to show the popup - so it will show when the mouse is in the window and hide when it is not. I cannot guess why :hover was used, but using only :target doesn't work as-coded because there can be only one element that matches the :target pseudo-class, so if you click on one of the showdiv1/showdiv2 links, the whole popup will disappear.
You will have to find a way to make a selector for the popup that matches BOTH when '__spooky_auth_popup' is the current target AND when either of the showdiv1/showdiv2 elements is the target. That will probably need re-structuring the document and using more complex selectors for the showdiv1/2 elements.